# Installing sfdisk 3.0

Tags: partitioning, software-installation, source-packages

I'm trying to install sfdisk 3.0 running  a live Ubuntu 18.04.1 LTS.  I have run all of this:

```
sudo add-apt-repository universe
sudo add-apt-repository restricted
sudo add-apt-repository multiverse
sudo add-apt-repository main
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install util-linux
sudo apt-cache show util-linux
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install libfdisk-dev
sudo apt-get install sfdisk
```

Then I get

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Package sfdisk is not available, but is referred to by another package.
This may mean that the package is missing, has been obsoleted, or
is only available from another source

E: Package 'sfdisk' has no installation candidate
```

What am I missing?

Comment: I think `sfdisk` is already installed - can you enter `which sfdisk`?  The program is part of the package `util-linux`

Answer (score 3):

On 18.04 LTS you should install `fdisk` package to obtain `/sbin/sfdisk` (see [packages.ubuntu.com for reference](https://packages.ubuntu.com/search?suite=bionic&arch=any&mode=exactfilename&searchon=contents&keywords=sfdisk)):

```
sudo apt install fdisk
```